# Anchor tag not working using Intent Share-Android

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, intentfilter

I want to share text, Image with clickable links in Gmail, facebook, twitter etc using intents.below is my code but it does not work. I have also put in link text in String resource file but does not work.The sharing functions as it should however when shared in a Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, etc. the link is ignored and the Gmail or tweet shows only plain text like this

```
private void share(Uri bmpUri)
{
    String hyperlink_url="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_3edWb68K4rT8gfx_pCoDw";

    String text = "here";
    String body = "<a href=\"" + hyperlink_url + "\">Click</a>";      
    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey! I just saw ABC is having XYZ through the my App! We should check it out."+ "\n" + Html.fromHtml(body));
    shareIntent.setType("text/html");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    //String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*","text/html"}; 
    // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes); 

    final List<ResolveInfo> activities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

    List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ResolveInfo info : activities) {
        appNames.add(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Complete Action using...");
    builder.setItems(appNames.toArray(new CharSequence[appNames.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            ResolveInfo info = activities.get(item);
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
                // Facebook was chosen
               // shareToFacebook();
            } else if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")) {
                // Twitter was chosen
                shareIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            } else {
                // start the selected activity
                shareIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```